# When iterating through a ruby array using .each do |x|, my code block is only executing once, what gives?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, each

Here is an example of the code that I have:

```
myArray = file.split("/n")
count = 0

myArray.each do |line|
    puts line
    count +=1
    puts count
end
```

myArray is filled with a very long string that I split into lines with the newline delimiter.
When I execute this script, every line the array is printed out, but count doesn't increment for each line. Maybe I am confused on the basics of array iteration but I was under the impression that each line inbetween my (do-end) would execute once per item in the array.

Example Data:

```
myArray = {dog, cat, mouse, bear, rat}
```

What results I get:

```
dog
cat
mouse
bear
rat
1
```

The .each do loops through all the items in the array first, and then adds to count only once. I thought that each time it printed one item, it would also increment count.

Answer (score 4):

newline should be `"\n"`

```
myArray = file.split("\n")
```

Comment: Well it's always the simple things we overlook right? Thank you!